# Epson XP 605 printer driver for ubuntu

Tags: drivers

does anyone know where I can download a printer driver for an Epson XP 605 all in one printer/copier/scanner

Comment: Epson XP 600 Drivers here , but i am not installed it yet, i think it will works [Epson XP 600 Drivers for Linux ](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/25367518/dir/rawhide/com/epson-inkjet-printer-escpr-1.3.1-1.1lsb3.2.fc21.i686.rpm.htmlsb3.2.fc21.i686.rpm.html)

Answer (score 3):

I've recently bought a Epson Expression Premium XP-600, which is the same as the XP-605 except it's black instead of white.

After you've connected your printer to your WiFi network simply go to *system settings* - *Printing*, *Add Printer*, expand *Network printer* and there you'll find your discovered printer.

The 'proprietary' driver is automatically downloaded and you just have to activate it.

Now printing works and you can use *Simple Scan* to scan your documents.

So far so good, but *Simple Scan* is very limited and applications like xsane won't find your scanner.

For more advanced scanning you want to use Image Scan! for Linux provided by Epson which you can find at the already mentioned [URL](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModuleFromResult?productname=XP-600&oscode=LX).

You'll need to download **iscan-data_1.22.0-1_all.deb** and the appropriate **iscan_2.29.1-5~usb0.1.*.deb** package (pick .ltdl7 for ubuntu 8.10 or higher).

Since the XP-600/605 is WiFi-only you'll also need a *network plugin package* which isn't offered at the XP-600's download page so you have to 'borrow' this from another model, for example the [PX720WD's](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModuleFromResult?productname=PX720WD&oscode=LX). Here you can download **iscan-network-nt_1.1.0-2_*.deb**.

Go to your download folder and doubleclick on the iscan-data package to install it through the Software Centre. After this you install the iscan package and the iscan-network-nt package.

Finally, you have to edit the /etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf file. To do this open terminal and type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf
```

Browse down through the file and look for the "#net 10.0.0.1" line, remove the # and change the 10.0.0.1 to the actual ip-address of your printer.

You can now use Image Scan! for Linux and as a bonus other scanner applications like xsane will now work with your scanner too.

Comment: where can i find iscan-data_1.22.0-1_all.deb?

Answer (score 0):

After searching the support catalog from Epson, I found these results for a "PX-605F". There were no results for an "XP 605".

http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModuleFromResult?productname=605&oscode=LX

Answer (score 0):

Linux drivers can be [found here](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModuleFromResult?productname=xp-600&oscode=LX).

There are separate drivers for printing and scanning. For Mint Linux 13, I downloaded the .deb files. I first had to install lsb

```
sudo apt-get install lsb
```

then

```
dpkg -i filename.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the required software when you search for "xp 600" in the ubuntu-software-center (ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: @Seth  Am I missing something, this looks like a legitimate answer to me (albeit short)